# how to access files in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, grails

I want to store the items, that I use in g:select in a file, that I can read at runtime.
My solution so far is to store the respective file under my project root and access the lines by

new File("myFile").each{selectList << it}

This approach is working fine with run-app in my ide. But when I generate the war and deploy it to tomcat the file is not deployed and the only way to access it is to move it manually to CATALINA_HOME/bin after deployment.

I know this is the newbie way and anything but professional.

I'm sure there is a better way, please tell me.

peter
dortmund, germany

Answer (score 0):

Current folder of the java application is different for run-app and tomcat. You can print it for example using

```
new File('.').absolutePath
```

So the approach could be to set path in config - different for production, different for development and create your file with

```
new File("${getPathFromConfig()}/$myFile}")
```

Also it may be easier to just store the list in the external config of your application in object format, so you don't need to read a file but it can be modified before application is started. See [this](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.1/guide/conf.html#configExternalized)

If you use groovy config, then you can just use the config option:

```
my.list=['option1', 'option2', ...]
```

and read it in application using

```
grailsApplication.config.my.list.each { ... }
```

hope this helps

Comment: I used the config.groovy approach, 1 line in config.groovy instead of 1 file. It works fine in run-app and tomcat

Comment: Additional question: I rather would leave Config.groovy untouched (except grails.config.location definition). Thus I would like to place the list definitions at the end of Config.groovy to a separate file inside my application.

Comment: Additional question: I rather would leave Config.groovy untouched (except grails.config.location definition). Thus I would like to place the list definitions at the end of Config.groovy to a separate file inside my application. That leads me to two questions: how should the file definition in grails.config.location = [....?????....] look like and where should the respective file be placed inside my application.

Comment: If file will be outside of application you can for example use:
def configLocations = ["file:${userHome}/${appName}/${appName}-config.groovy"] and put the file to /home/username/AppName/AppName-config.groovy on linux or c:\users\username\AppName\AppName-config.groovy on windows

Comment: anyway, apart from storing the config-lines in a separate file. I just figured out that  grailsApplication.config is not available in a domain class, and that is were I need it. My first tests were in a controller.

Comment: replacing grailsApplication.config by grails.util.Holders.config makes it working in domain class too

Comment: it seems like a really complicated way of doing it. if you use domain classes and database, why don't you store those values in DB? if you want to display lists in view, you should pass it to view model instead of additing it to domain class method.

Answer (score 0):

First create a directory in your app configuration folder. Suppose you have created a directory

```
conf_data.
```

secont now define file path in your config.groovy file

```
app.demo.data.folder.location = "conf_data/demoData.xml"
```

finaly use

```
def demoDataFileLocation = new GroovyClassLoader(ConfigurationHolder.classLoader).getResource(grailsApplication.config.app.demo.data.folder.location).file.toString()

def demoDataRecords = new XmlParser().parse(demoDataFileLocation)
```

now you have path of your file in demoDatafileLocation you can use as you want